# how to select all combination of column names and do calculation on those columns in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset that contains 81 columns with person id, 79 binary variables and a cost variable:

```
id h1 h2 h3 ... h79  cost
1  1  0  1      1     15
2  1  1  1      1     80
3  0  1  1      0     10
...
```

each person id have one row of records. Now I want to choose which of the two h(binary) variables have more than 50 unique person id. if then do calculate their total cost. 
I guess a good way to approach it is to create a array with all h variables and use two DO LOOPS? But what if I want to see a group of three variables or maybe four or five? And also how am I going to store the combination of variable names so I could know this combination of variables has this amount of total cost. So I think the final output is going to looks like this:

```
combinations              total cost
h1&h3                       95
h2&h3                       90
h1&h2&h3.                   80
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: Does "choose which of the two h(binary) variables have more than 50 unique person id" mean "choose every pair of h variables that are (1,1) and occur in more than 50 ids"

Comment: How many rows are there ? comb(79,2) = 3081, comb(79,3) = 79079, comb (79,4) = 1502501 and comb(79,5) = 22537515  -- that is a lot of searching for each row !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DATA step can use the `ALLCOMB` or `ALLCOMBI` routines to iterate through the k-subset combinations of an array of size n.  A hash can be use to accumulate the count and total cost of each specific k-subset asserting all true conditions.

```
options mprint;

data have (keep=id flag: cost);
  do id = 1 to 3;
    array flag(79) flag01-flag79;
    do i = 1 to dim(flag);
      flag(i) = ranuni(1) < 0.5;
    end;
    cost = ceil(10+100*ranuni(123));
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Example

```
data _null_;
  if 0 then set have;* prep pdv;

  array x flag:;
  n = dim(x);

  k = 2; ways2 = comb(dim(x),k); put 'NOTE: ' n= k= ways2=;
  k = 3; ways3 = comb(dim(x),k); put 'NOTE: ' n= k= ways3=;
  k = 4; ways4 = comb(dim(x),k); put 'NOTE: ' n= k= ways4=;
  k = 5; ways5 = comb(dim(x),k); put 'NOTE: ' n= k= ways5=;

  array var(5) $32;
  length count cost_sum 8;

  declare hash all_true(hashexp:15, ordered:'A');
  all_true.defineKey('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5');
  all_true.defineData('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'count', 'cost_sum');
  all_true.defineDone();

  do until (end);
    set have end=end;
    array f flag:;

    %macro track_all_true(K=);

      array index&K._[&K];
      call missing (of index&K._[*]);  %* reset search tracking variables;
      call missing (of var[*]);        %* reset search tracking variables;

      %* search all combinations for those that are all true;
      do p = 1 to comb(n,&K);

        call allcombi(n, &K, of index&K._[*], add, remove);

        %* check each item in the combination;
        do q = 1 to &K while(x[index&K._[q]]);
        end;

        if q > &K then do; %* each item was true;
          do q = 1 to &K;
            which_index = index&K._[q];
            which_var = vname( x[which_index] );
            var(q) = which_var;
          end;

          if all_true.find() ne 0 then do; %* track first occurrence of the combination;
            cost_sum = cost;
            count = 1;
            all_true.add();
          end;
          else do; %* accumulate count and cost information for the combination;
            cost_sum + cost;
            count + 1;
            all_true.replace();
          end;
        end;

      end;

    %mend;

    %track_all_true(K=2)
    %track_all_true(K=3)

    %track_all_true(K=4)
    %track_all_true(K=5)

  end;

  all_true.output(dataset:'count_cost');
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your code I tried on my data which has around 30K rows and it runs perfectly well. Thanks for showing me how to use hash table to do this. It's my first time to use hash table and I really learned

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to use PROC SUMMARY.

```
data have ;
input id h1 h2 h3 h79 cost ;
cards;
1  1  0  1      1     15
2  1  1  1      1     80
3  0  1  1      0     10
;

proc summary data=have chartype ;
   class h1-h3 ;
   var cost ;
   output out=cost_summary sum= ;
run;
```

But you are only interested in the results where all of the contributing class variables have a value of 1.

```
proc print data=cost_summary ;
  where min(h1,h2,h3) = 1 ;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    h1    h2    h3    _TYPE_    _FREQ_    cost

  2     .     .     1     001         3       105
  4     .     1     .     010         2        90
  6     .     1     1     011         2        90
  8     1     .     .     100         2        95
 10     1     .     1     101         2        95
 13     1     1     .     110         1        80
 16     1     1     1     111         1        80
```

Comment: thanks Tom. I guess it works when you have 3 binary variables in class. But I have 79 binary variables so I don't think SAS can handle that many class variables in PROC SUMMARY.

Comment: Try using `WAYS` statement or other methods to limit the combinations.